# Core Data memory issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management

I am inserting thousands of data into my SQLite stored Core data .
My ManagedObjectContext's undomanager set to nil.
I am inserting NSManagedObject in a for loop.
tried saving the context in two way,

1 after completion of loop (outside the for loop).

```
for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){

        MyEntity *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        object.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];


    }

    [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

2 for every  insertion (inside the for loop).

```
for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){

        MyEntity *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        object.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];

    }
```

and finally i called reset for ManagedObjectContext .

```
[[self managedObjectContext] reset];
```

but the problem is memory taken for this process(insertion) is not get back after the completion.

Can any one suggest me whats is wrong with this, or this is the expected behavior ?
Any workaround for avoiding this memory leak?

**UPDATE**

I tried  `[[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];`
It can put back some amount of memory, but not fully.Still searching a good solution for managing large amount of data in `CoreData`.

If  any one suggest me an example project(source code) which handle large amount of data in `CoreData`,then will be helpful for me .
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem in our project. Reseting the context barely freed any memory. Turns out the problem was fixed when reset was done on all parent contexts:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext = context;

while (currentContext) {

    [currentContext reset];
    currentContext = [currentContext parentContext];
}
```

Comment: This worked like charm, I was only calling reset only for context and parent contexts were still holding the memory. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is subject of autorelease pool issues. Without authorelease application will keep memory some time (only apple guys know, how much time. If you like to take process in your hands, just change you code:

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

```
for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){

        MyEntity *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        object.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
        [pool drain], pool = nil;
        pool =  [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    }
 [pool drain], pool = nil;
```

Comment: it doesnt put back  the used memory

Comment: using activity monitor in mac

Comment: looks like Galazas0 gives my idea and represent better :) anyway, that must help

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks autoreleasepools :D this means you're storing 1000 MyEntity objects in memory, and this WILL lead to crashes and iOS will FC your app (force close). The code should look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
                MyEntity *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

                object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
                object.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        }
    }
    [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

OR:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        MyEntity *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        object.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        [pool drain];
    }
    [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

Also, this may not be the best way to do this kind of thing, I would suggest adding it to the context, then operating on the context itself perhaps using

`[[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] name] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];`

or something of the sort. This way you don't create a local copy of the object and clog up your memory.

Using the last of three methods, I would do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] name] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] age] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    }
    [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

And if this MyEntity is your own custom class, you can even simplify your code by using

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) id name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) id age;
```

Replace `id name` and `id age` with the correct variable and object class, and this way your code will be even simpler:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] setName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
        [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] setAge: [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    [self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

Hope this helps and doesn't confuse you!

Comment: I tried NSAutoreleasePool but it doesnt give me the used memory back..and I couldnt find any [NSEntityDescription objectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity"] method.

Comment: Something else you could do is operate directly on the object in the context, so let me edit my code to show you how to do that.

Comment: If you think this answer helped you, please mark it as correct! :]

Comment: Sorry Galaxas its not working ,        [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] name] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]; this will give error "Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed" and this will [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] setName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]]; cause crash also ..

Comment: did you set the properties for it correctly? it should be @property(nonatomic, retain) id age;// or id name; and replace id with the types of the variable correctly.

Comment: Ya I did correctly ..and you know [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] will return NSEntityDescription not NSManagedObject..we cannot set property value for NSEntityDescription ,because  MyEntity is a subclass of NSManagedObject...I think understand this ..thank you

Comment: so then you'd have to find the right method to get the NSManagedObject out of the NSEntityDescription, but that's a different question altogether. :]

Comment: But still there is no  appropriate answer for my question..I tried the NSAutoreleasePool but it cant give up complete memory back..

Comment: How much memory does it take before you implement the autorelease pool, and how much did it take after you did?

Comment: it depends on how big the data is ..autorelease pool will avoid memory warning and crash ,

Comment: Hmm... could you try sharing more of your code with us, so we can help in rewriting to avoid this issue?

Comment: The code is complex for the reader since it contain lots of relationships (the section having above 40 lines of code), if i post that piece of code my question will be down voted ,I m very sorry

Comment: Alright then, if you're still having trouble you'll need to be more specific, but I'm afraid I can't help you anymore, as I've already tried to diagnose the issue as much as possible.

Comment: Ya I know , and I m very happy for that because I hope you did good effort for finding out my problem.Any way I found any progress in this issue will update.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation! :]

Answer (score 1):

while this is a bit late,

i found that setting `undo` to `nil` did not help, but the following did prevent leaks in core data.

```
[[self managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges];  // flush operations
[[[self managedObjectContext] undoManager] disableUndoRegistration]; // disable undo
```

regarding autoreleasepool. hitting an exception (including as Numberformat exception) `object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];` your pool will not drain as desired. in fact, another autoreleasepool will drain all autoreleased instances. memory will leak, such as the exception which is created via autorelease. so the following is suggested.

```
NSException *myexception = nil;

try {
   .... [yadda yadda];
} catch (NSException e)
{
   myexception = [e retain];
   @throw;    
}
finally {
    [pool drain];
    [myexception release];
}
```

i would suggest not putting in the autoreleasepool, sort out whether `[[[self managedObjectContext] undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];` helps on a smaller set and then move larger. undo manager in core data is a leaky boat, and i have not figured out a solution.